# How to append element using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have variable array of objects, one of which is contains element **p** in the string. And I want to append to element **div.profile-description**

But the result is vue js return raw html to **div.profile-description**

I want to **p in the string** become element in **html**

```js
var interviewees = [
  {name: 'Anthony', profession: 'Developer', description: '<p>Now he works in one</p><p>very famous company</p>'},
  {name: 'Erick', profession: 'Gamer', description: '<p>He is focusing on playing</p><p>the heroes of the storm game</p>'}
];

var setDescription = new Vue({
 el: '.profile-description',
 data: {
  interviewee_description: interviewees[1].description
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<div class="profile-description">
  {{ interviewee_description }}
</div>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use the `v-html` directive:

```
<div v-html="interviewee_description" class="profile-description"></div>
```

Alert:

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very
> dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use
> HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided
> content.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Answer (score 3):

Use the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive.

```
<div class="profile-description">
  <div v-html="interviewee_description"></div>
</div>
```

Typically, you should use a selector that only returns a single element. `class` will have unexpected results if there are more than one that match your selector.

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ybMeJW).